# How does react re-render components when components is subscribed to a list

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, render, react-component

Consider a react-redux app. Let's suppose I've a list in my redux state:
`{ filters: [{id:'a'}, {id:'b'}, {id:'c'}]}`. Component A is subscribed to filters and it generates a list of component B which has property `b` that would be filled by each object in the list. If `filters` is updated, would all the B components be re-rendered?

Comment: depends on how b is getting receiving the updated array and whether a new instance of the array is created on filters change

Comment: @shubham-khatri As Redux replaces the state with a new instance, can I be sure that whole the components generated by list would be re-rendered?

Comment: @rezKesh Yes you can be sure of that.

Comment: @shubham-khatri Thanks. Was it a junk question? Should I remove it?

Comment: In present state, the question isn't descriptive enough to be useful for others. However you should edit it with more and clear details about the problem such as how the component B is rendered and how it receives data